# Nuxt dynamic layout base on domain name?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm planning to develop white label project using nuxtJS (Universal Mode). My idea is when user come to the nuxtJS using difference domain, it will display difference layout.

For example,
if user A access [www.aaa.com](http://www.aaa.com) --> with show layout on `layouts/aaa/default.vue` path

if user A access [www.bbb.com](http://www.bbb.com) --> with show layout on `layouts/bbb/default.vue` path

anyone has an idea or an example how to handle this?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a strange setup, but if you're sure it's what you want; you could set up a middleware to check the origin of the request and return a value that can be used to determine the layout in your page files.

**myMiddleware.js**

```
export default function({ req, redirect }) {
  let host = req.get('host');
  if (host.includes('aaa')) {
    return 'aaaLayout.vue'
  } else if (host.includes('bbb') {
    return 'bbbLayout.vue'
  }
}
```

Then in your pages:

```
import middleware from '@/middleware/myMiddleware'
...
layout: middleware
```

May need tweaking to suit your exact needs, but something like that would work.

Comment: Why would this be a strange setup? How would you handle a multi-tenant web app?

Comment: Same issue here. Is this possible with Nuxt3? I have different domain names in different countries and each country should be served its unique layout. Did you find any solution @EricDelaCruz ?

Comment: @Gabriel I don't have this requirement so I didn't look for a solution. I also switched from Vue to Sveltekit. Sveltekit has a lot of layout options. I'm sure it would be possible to solve this using Sveltekit. But personally, I probably would use different css files not different layout components.